# installing steam on 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04, steam

I'm trying to install steam (deb or terminal, it has to not be flatpak or snap)

and I tried following the first method on this website:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

```
sudo apt install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386 libapparmor1:i386
  libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libbrotli1:i386
  libcairo2:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdecor-0-0:i386
  libdecor-0-plugin-1-cairo:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libegl-mesa0:i386
  libegl1:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386
  libfribidi0:i386 libgbm1:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386
  libharfbuzz0b:i386 libigdgmm12:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libogg0:i386
  libopus0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386
  libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386
  libpng16-16:i386 libpulse0:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386
  libsndfile1:i386 libthai0:i386 libva2:i386 libvorbis0a:i386
  libvorbisenc2:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxi6:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386
  libxss1:i386 mesa-va-drivers:i386 steam-devices va-driver-all:i386
Suggested packages:
  i965-va-driver-shaders:i386 jackd2:i386 opus-tools:i386
  libnvidia-gl-390:i386 | libnvidia-gl-470:i386 | libnvidia-gl-495:i386
  pipewire:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386 libapparmor1:i386
  libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libbrotli1:i386
  libcairo2:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdecor-0-0:i386
  libdecor-0-plugin-1-cairo:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libegl-mesa0:i386
  libegl1:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386
  libfribidi0:i386 libgbm1:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386
  libharfbuzz0b:i386 libigdgmm12:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libogg0:i386
  libopus0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386
  libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386
  libpng16-16:i386 libpulse0:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386
  libsndfile1:i386 libthai0:i386 libva2:i386 libvorbis0a:i386
  libvorbisenc2:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxi6:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386
  libxss1:i386 mesa-va-drivers:i386 steam:i386 steam-devices
  va-driver-all:i386
```

I did do `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` even though that's not part of the guide I'm following (it was for wine) should I revert and disable i386 first and then try installing steam again?

The long list of packages seems off to me.

Comment: It looks OK to me. Steam requires i386.

Comment: ok thank I'll go ahead and install.